# How to access array of objects subelement from redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a response from an API like this one:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "status": true,
    "consoles": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Xbox",
        "status": true,
        "subconsoles": [{
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Xbox 360",
            "status": true,
            "subconsoles": []
        },
    {
            "id": 90,
            "name": "Xbox One",
            "status": false,
            "subconsoles": [{
            "id": 21,
            "name": "Xbox One S",
            "status": true,
            "subconsoles": []
        },
      {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Xbox One X",
            "status": false,
            "subconsoles": [{
                "id": 41,
                "name": "Xbox One X model 1",
                "status": false,
                "subconsoles": []
            }]
        }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Here is also the data in nice format:

[image: Online JSON Viewer]

What I am trying to achieve is to modify the status of the subconsoles.
So from layout section I pass the ID of what I want to change, but I am really stuck on how to access the subelement (and eventually the sub-subelement) in the reducers of Redux:

```
case SUBCONSOLES_ENABLE:
return {
    ...state,
    id: action.payload.subconsoleId,
    .....
}
```

Comment: Can you show some actual data? This appears to be malformed

Comment: I have added an image with the JSON view in a nice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a copy of each of the arrays you have in your state before you can change them, to keep your state immutable. With so many levels, that would get complicated fast!

```
case SUBCONSOLES_ENABLE:
let newState = [...state]; //create copy of state array
.....   //find the index of the object in the newState array which you would want to change
let newConsoles = [...newState[index].consoles]; //create a copy of consoles
.....           //find the index of the object in the newConsoles array which you would want to change
let newSubConsoles = [...newConsoles[index2].subconsoles];//create a copy of subconsoles
 let subConsole = newSubConsoles.find((a)=>a.id===action.payload.subconsoleId); //find the object in the newConsoles array which you would want to change 
  let newSubConsole = {...subConsole}             //make a copy of your object
  .....                                          //make your changes to the copy 
                                                 //replace the old object with the new object in newSubConsoles
                                                 //replace subConsoles array with newSubConsoles array in newConsoles
                                                 // replace consoles array with newConsoles array in new State.
 //and finally!!                                          
return newState;
```

Based on the shape of your state, I would suggest looking at [normalizing your state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) and using [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the update fn from the ['immutability-helper' library](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), its recommended in the react docs themselves.